# Is it possible to modify (add a feature to) the iPod application on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I love the iPod application on the iPhone, but I wish a had a really simple way of saying "Play this next". Other small additional features could do wonders as well. Is it possible to modify the iPod application or in some way add a feature?

Comment: Why not just write your own...  If you really think it's a good idea, write it, then sell it through the app store.

Comment: @CodaFi I only really think it's a good idea when included in the existing fully blown professional media application. It certainly doesn't justify writing a whole new media app from scrath.

Comment: Well, it's my way or the highway.  Even if you could gain access to the iPod app, you'd find maybe a couple images, and a ton of unix executables.  There is no way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't.  First, Apple doesn't give you access to the source code for the app, which you would need.  Also, Apple doesn't provide any api to allow modifications to its apps.  You can access data (the songs themselves) so if you really want it to be different, you'll have to write your own app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible..Apple only provide you to **use data from only few of is own apps**..so updating them is out of the question